# POST variables to model is not working in php codeigniter by using return in success

Tags: javascript, php

I tried the following code:

```
function doAjax() {

        var sList = "";
                        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
                            sList += (sList=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
                        });

     $.ajax({
            url: "UserRights/update_rights",
            type: "POST",
            data:{ X : sList},
            success: function(data) {
           // alert("Success:"+data);
            return data;
      }
        });
    };
```

In model:

```
function update_userright()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['X']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['X']))
        {

            $checkbox_list =$this->input->post('X');
            echo "Posted".$checkbox_list;   

        }
    }
    else
    {

        echo "Nothing";
        /* $active=$this->input->post('menulist');
        echo "Posted values .$active";
        $sql= $this->db->query("UPDATE UserRightsNew SET Active='$active' WHERE UserCode='$default_usercode'; "); */
    }   

}
```

When i tried with alert message the values are posted but the return(data) is not working ... anybody guide me?

Comment: Check your browser console for error!!

Comment: yah i tried but i couldn't find out...

Comment: Try to add `,error: function(e){ alert(e); };` after success for you to see errors.

Comment: Also try to add `dataType: "html"` after `data`. This may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in JavaScript. Try this.

```
function doAjax() {

        var sList = sThisVal = "";
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
             sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
             sList += (sList=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
                        });
     var result = '';
     $.ajax({
            url: "UserRights/update_rights",
            type: "POST",
            data:{ X : sList},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: "+data);
            result = data;
            }, error: function(e){
              alert(e); //To show errors
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

MODEL

```
update_userright(); //make sure to execute the function
function update_userright()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['X']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['X']))
        {

            $checkbox_list =$this->input->post('X');
            echo "Posted".$checkbox_list;   

        }
    }
    else
    {

        echo "Nothing";
        /* $active=$this->input->post('menulist');
        echo "Posted values .$active";
        $sql= $this->db->query("UPDATE UserRightsNew SET Active='$active' WHERE UserCode='$default_usercode'; "); */
    }   

}
```

Comment: Here i call the doajax function in button click and just i need to post the data values to model... so in success part i don't need alert box just  i want to return the values.

Comment: So you mean the problem is the model does not receive the data you sent from AJAX.